# Unity Game Crashes on IOS with Message didRecieveMemoryWarnining

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have developed a game in unity. Which works fine on android but when I tested it on IOS my game crashes after playing 3 levels. I have tested it using XCODE 8. Before crashing didRecieveMemeoryWarning() appear and then "**game terminated due to memory issue**" . I have compressed my all textures. Double checked my code.I did everything that I can think of. Plz guys help me.

Comment: On what device? You can see the memory usage in xcode. Watch how much memory the app is used before it gets killed by iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Right After building your game, You can see how big your game is and how many space is taking every file included, to see this, right click on the console tab and select "Open Editor Log" as mentioned in [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html). If there is some files that are taking too many space, consider reducing its size, with textures/sprites is as easy as setting a max size to a lower value.

If your build is fine in Android it may be that your textures/sprites are not in a size power of 2 (like 128x128, 256x256, 512x512, and so on...). Unity can't compress this images unless they are power of 2 in iOS.

To solve the above problem without having to manually change every texture of your game, I recommend using packing tags in your sprite options, you can assign the same tags to sprites so they create an atlas, see [documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html). Normally you want to pack together sprites that belong to the same level or menu and try avoiding having atlases bigger than 2048x2048, to see your atlases you can go to the Sprite Packer Window.